# Is it possible to use several different ssl certificates on the same ASP.NET website depending on the Subdomain used?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm running an ASP.NET MVC website on IIS7 secured with a wildcard SSL certificate issued by StartSSL.

Usually a wildcard certificate is very expensive, but we need the extra subdomain functionality. Fortunately the wildcard certificate issued by StartSSL certificate is very cheap and supported by all modern desktop browsers, so it worked fine for me so far.

But now I have developed a mobile version of our website and there are lots of mobile devices / browsers that issue a warning about not being able to verify the SSL certificate's authenticity (Windows Phone 7 and Opera 10 Mobile are the most prominent examples).

Would it be possible to use our existing wildcard certificate for all subdomains on our website except one or two and use a Thawte or Verisign certificate for those few subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As certificate validation happens before the web server can know which subdomain the client requests, you can only do this by placing the subdomains on different IPs.